# PostBack ist not executed after FileUpload.click() on some machines

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I have created a WebControl. Where is a button for uploading a file.

I create the Button and the FileUpload like

```
private readonly Button button;
public DocumentUploadButton() {
    button = new Button();
    button.Click += this.ProcessClick;
    var panel = new Panel();
    panel.Controls.Add(button);
    var fileUpload = new FileUpload();
    fileUpload.ID = "fileUploadHidden";
    fileUpload.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";

    panel.Controls.Add(fileUpload);
    Controls.Add(panel);
}

private void ProcessClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (this.fileUpload.PostedFile != null &&  string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName)) {
       // Upload file and handle it like ...
       this.fileUpload.SaveAs(....)
    }
}
```

in the OnLoad I attach a JavaScript-Function:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
   this.button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('fileUploadHidden').click();");
   base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Now, when the user clicks the button, the FileUpload is invoked and shows the FileChooseDialog. This is working great. But after this, the Click-Handler ProcessFile() is not executed on some customer machines (i think the PostBack is not executed). On my developer-Machine this is working ok.

Can someone help me, what can be going wrong on customer-machines?

We use InternetExplorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably IE security Settings, at least in my cases in the past. Ask them to add the site to trusted sites on their machine